# Creating indexes for Mongoid within my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

So I have a rake task that runs regularly and afterwards I need to create my indexes again, is there a way I can call those methods directly in ruby without resorting to sending them to the system to execute like this:

```
task :mytask => :environment do
  # do stuff...
  `bundle exec rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make direct calls to other rake tasks in your application with `Rake::Task`. So your above code could become:

```
task :mytask => :environment do
  # do stuff...
  Rake::Task['db:mongoid:create_indexes']
end
```